# How to remove "extern" functions in C and be able to use them from golang?

Tags: c, go, interop, cgo

I have a C wrapper of C++ library that I want to use with golang. Overall path of callback that I want is golang->C->C++. I tested part C->C++, but face difficulties with golang->C part.

As said in wiki, I tried this [example](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#function-variables). It works good on linux, but when I compile it on windows it fails on "extern" keyword because I compile C library and golang separately.

I thought that it is possible to split C library on part that doesn't know about golang at all. And put this callback with "extern" keyword into golang directory. But I think this will not fit me because function that takes callback and I need looks like this:

```c
ClipperPaths64 *
clipper_clipperoffset_execute_gocallback(void *mem, ClipperClipperOffset *c, uintptr_t h) {
        auto result = new (mem) Paths64();
        from_c(c)->Execute(from_c(h), *result);
        return to_c(result);
}
```

You see that I use `from_c(...)` functions and they return C++ objects, they are not exposed publicly of this library and I cannot use them.

I would share more code if it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is solved and as reference you may peek my repo: [here](https://github.com/epit3d/goclipper2)

Solution:
Just move function that is "extern" to directory of golang module. You will compile separately C/C++ library and alongside golang code you can place callbacks and whatever you will define in golang file.

Example of callback.c:

```c
// define delta callback
double delta_callback(
    uintptr_t h,
    ClipperPath64 *path, ClipperPathD *path_normals,
    size_t curr_idx, size_t prev_idx)
{
    return goDeltaCallback64(h, path, path_normals, curr_idx, prev_idx);
}
```

callback.h:

```c
#ifndef CLIBRARY_H
#define CLIBRARY_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include "../lib/clipper2c/clipper2c.h"

typedef double (*callbackfunc) (
    uintptr_t h, ClipperPath64 *path, ClipperPathD *path_normals,
                    size_t curr_idx, size_t prev_idx);

double delta_callback(
    uintptr_t h,
    ClipperPath64 *path, ClipperPathD *path_normals,
    size_t curr_idx, size_t prev_idx);

extern double goDeltaCallback64(uintptr_t h, ClipperPath64 *path,
                                ClipperPathD *path_normals, size_t curr_idx,
                                size_t prev_idx);

#endif
```

.go:

```golang
//export goDeltaCallback64
func goDeltaCallback64(
    h C.uintptr_t,
    path *C.ClipperPath64,
    path_normals *C.ClipperPathD,
    curr_idx C.size_t,
    prev_idx C.size_t,
) C.double {
    fn := cgo.Handle(h).Value().(ClipperOffsetCallback)

    gopath := &Path64{
        p: path,
    }

    gopath_normals := &PathD{
        p: path_normals,
    }

    return C.double(fn(gopath, gopath_normals, int(curr_idx), int(prev_idx)))
}
```